# How To Check A Value Exists In Table From An Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a list of combinations which is coming from a function;
i have an array

```
$new_array=array(5 random values);


$new_array = array(); // create a new array
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5") or die("query Field");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $new_array[] = $row['code'];

 }
```

Suppose I have these values in the array

```
$new_array=array('a','c','d','e','t','s');
```

i have all the possible permutations which is coming from a function.

Now I want to find out either these permutations exists in the table or not .
I have tried with select query but failed .

My permutation function is given below

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array()) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
        echo join(' ', $perms) . "<br />";
    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}

$arr = $new_array;
$a=count(pc_permute($arr));
```

I am stuck , I am trying from last 3 hours but failed I want to check whether these permutations exists in the mysql table or not .

Comment: Show us the query you tried

Comment: Do values repeat. For example, can you get 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' from the function? If all values are unique in both the function and the table, there is a very very quick and easy solution.

Comment: all the values are unique the are randomly generated from the query such as $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animate ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8") or die("query Field");

Answer (score 0):

Because all values are unique, there is a solution that may suit your needs. The query is:

```
select * from YOURTABLE where
VALUE like '%$val1%'
and VALUE like '%$val2%'
and VALUE like '%$val3%
etc...
```

Assume you have an array called $new_array that has 5 indexes. You can use the query:

```
$query = "select * from words where
lemma like '%".$new_array[0]."%'
and lemma like '%".$new_array[1]."%'
and lemma like '%".$new_array[2]."%'
and lemma like '%".$new_array[3]."%'
and lemma like '%".$new_array[4]."%'
and lemma like '%".$new_array[5]."%'";
```

Because you don't state in the question, I have no clue what the table's actual name is or the column's actual name. I also don't know how you get the 5 random values for your $new_array array.

<s>What you are asking is for a value where it contains each of the elements you got from your function. It will get all values regardless of the permutation. I am assuming that you already have the skills to write the query using the array indexes instead of $val1, $val2, and so on. If not, please ask.</s>

The obvious advantage here is that you don't have to calculate all the permutations and you don't have to send multiple queries.

Comment: where i should use this query becuase all values are directly coming from permutation function

 
   SELECT wordid FROM `words` WHERE lemma LIKE 'what i should use here'

Comment: You said that you have an array of values that you called $new_array. Do you have that? If so, see the edit I will make in a second...

Comment: OK. Now you have $new_array. So, use it to make the query I wrote. Query the database and you will get every row in which lemma is a permutation of $new_array.

Comment: yes it is restricted to 5 indices can we make more generalise by iterating through a loop?

Comment: Yes. My example is hard-coded for 6 indexes. You can generate the query in a for loop or by using implode.

Comment: if you could make it from a loop I shall be very thankful to you